# Passing vector with std::ref to threads does not seem to update the actual vector rather threads only updating local vector copy

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, stdthread

I am facing a strange issue when passing a vector std::ref to pool of threads.

I cannot put the exact code but I have something like :
**Approach A**

```
void myfunc(int start, int end, std::vector<double>& result)
{
   for(int i=start; i<end; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = ...
    }
}


vector<double> myvec(N);
const size_t num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.reserve(num_threads);

for(int idx=0; idx<num_threads; ++idx)
   threads.push_back(std::thread(myfunc, (idx*nloop/num_threads), (idx+1)*nloop/num_threads), std::ref(myvec)));

for(std::thread& t : threads)
  { 
    if(t.joinable())
     t.join();
  }

some_read_opration(myvec)...
```

But if I explicitly create threads and divide tasks by hard coding ranges, it gives me expected values.

This works:
**Approach B**

```
std::thread t1(myfunc, 0, nloop/2, std::ref(myvec));
std::thread t2(myfunc, nloop/2, nloop, std::ref(myvec));

t1.join();
t2.join();

some_read_opration(myvec)...
```

I want parallelize my loop in more generic way, not sure where I am going wrong here.
In the A approach : The issue I am facing is that, it seems like each thread updates `result[]` element locally but its not being reflected at `myvec` in the function which creates threads, even if I am passing `std::ref(myvec)`.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Add enough logging to ensure that every thread gets the expected range and that every thread has completed before the main thread proceeds. Rule out the obvious problems first.

Comment: please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: `N == nloops` ? are they `int` ?

Comment: To follow on @idclev463035818's suggestion, it seems likely that the start/end of the range passed to `myfunc` is 0, because of truncation in the division when you create each thread. So no work is being done.

Comment: I am guessing ```myfunc``` threads are racing with the main thread and haven't completed work

Comment: In " Approach A" example, there are more closing parentheses than opening ones. Also, `nloop` is an undeclared identifier. Show the actual code you compile and run.

Comment: And, fixing that, [cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oxd3QYpMMgzwge75).

Comment: Thank you all for the response, thank specially you @DavidSchwartz : that debug really helped, my ranges were getting messed up and belive it or not it got solved by proper use of parenthesis , I had start range caluculated something like (int * int/int) and had to put ((int) * (int/int)). For ex. (2 * 3/2) = 3  vs  ((2) * (3/2)) = (2 * 1) = 2. Also, thanks for all the feedback this was my first question on stackoverflow, I ll make sure next time I have minimal reproducible example.